# How to update Dart SDK in ubuntu without updating Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, upgrade, dart

So I am working on creating an e-commerce App in flutter. I am using flutter version 1.22.6 for Ubuntu (18.04.5 LTS). I don't want to upgrade my flutter version as it generated lots of issues to my colleagues. For me the problem is that i have to use a lot of packages for my Application which requires most recent Dart SDK. So is it possible to upgrade just the Dart SDK while keeping the same version of Flutter.

Comment: If you have used detail versions of packages in pubspec, all will be ok. If no, just specify versions at moment, forexample month ago. You can see versions in pub.dev version history tab .

Answer (score 1):

Probably not,
The reason for this is flutter is the framework and of course, it depends on dart language version. Why?

For example, If we compare 2 dart sdk between flutter 1.x version and flutter 2, we can see flutter ver 2 depends on dart sdk which supports null safety while flutter ver 1.x does not support null safety.

In the end, if you upgrade somehow the dart sdk without upgrading flutter sdk too, you will see many errors in flutter framework.

Comment: So,That means Flutter does not want to use my local Dart Sdk, right? And it requires the same  version of Dart which comes along with it or it causes errors. So, I think my only hope here is to downgrade the packages i'm using right now to support my current Dart Sdk.